# Arabic text takes time to load in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, fonts

I'm working on a Quran app.
I'm trying to display each pages as cells in a tableview. The text is in arabic and I've tried with system font and custom fonts to display the pages.

The problem is, when then text used to display in a cell is large, the cell takes time to load and this interrupts the main thread and the tableview gets stuck while scrolling.

I have tried both 'Attributted text' and 'plain text'
I have checked and confirmed that the font I use supports all the characters in my text.

Following is the code I'm using to set the text. The problem persists even when the string is hardcoded with some arabic text.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   

   QuranCell *cell = (QuranCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"quranCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.lblQuranText.attributedText = arrayQuranText[indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
```

This problem is not there if I use 'english' text. The problem is specific to 'arabic' text. Loading time increases when the size of the text is increased.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome..

Comment: setting the text should be done in mainthread as it is a UI process right?

Comment: Don't know why it is getting down votted.  I've posted this in SO after searching and trying out different methods for 2 days.

Comment: You made cell custom or protoType in storyboard ?

Comment: I've tried out using both custom cell and using the cell.textLabel. The cell don't have any other subviews. I think it is the problem with arabic text as the issue is not there for english text. May be the rendering of arabic text is taking time.

Comment: can you add code cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Added the datasource method.

Comment: try to set cell.lblQuranText.clipsToBounds = YES ;